# Broadcast receiver to intercept switching between 3g and GPRS in SDK or NDK

Tags: android, android-intent, android-ndk, broadcastreceiver

It is possibile in Android to intercept switching between 3g and GPRS, LTE, EDGE with a broadcast receiver to call a method when mobile data connection changes?

Attention: the problem is not how can i get informations, but how can i INTERCEPT the EVENT!

Thank you.

Update: I accept answer with NDK ;) because, probably, is not possibile with SDK :(

Comment: These might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/9703409/1979347 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/24191919/1979347

Comment: One more for you http://stackoverflow.com/q/9283765/1979347

Comment: The first method is not working. The problem is still open, like and-dev says in the last comment. The second one is not working, because i tried with the 3 event not in wifi package without success.

Comment: The third solution is not an answer because i want to intercept THE EVENT and not to call a method to get the network type (this is very simple).

Comment: You are making us confuse. What do you mean by 'i want to intercept'? Please clarify.

Comment: I mean the event. I want a system that automatically call a method when the mobile connectivity changes. I don't want to call anything. When the connection changes, a receiver starts and execute automatically some code. 
If i want to realize this between wifi and mobile data is extremely simple (like in the page that you posted), but between edge and 3G for example it's not working.

Comment: Ok probably is not possibile to use this function. I read a huge amount of q&a on stackoverflow without success. If someone has other ideas please write ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)

> The primary responsibilities of this class are to:
>
> 1. Monitor network connections (Wi-Fi, GPRS, UMTS, etc.)
> 2. Send broadcast intents when network connectivity changes
> 3. Attempt to "fail over" to another network when connectivity to a network is lost
> 4. Provide an API that allows applications to query the coarse-grained or fine-grained state of the available networks
> 5. Provide an API that allows applications to request and select networks for their data traffic

See training [Determining and Monitoring the Connectivity Status](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)

**Update:**

> According answer [Emil Davtyan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8548926/940720)
>
> If the problem is to find whether the phone's network is connected and
>   fast enough to meet your demands you have to handle all the network
>   types returned by `getSubType()`.
>
> It took me an hour or two to research and write this class to do just
>   exactly that, and I thought I would share it with others that might
>   find it useful.
>
> Here is a [Gist of the class](https://gist.github.com/emil2k/5130324), so you can fork it and edited it.
>
> ```
> package com.emil.android.util;
>
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
> import android.net.NetworkInfo;
> import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
>
> /**
>  * Check device's network connectivity and speed 
>  * @author emil https://stackoverflow.com/users/220710/emil
>  *
>  */
> public class Connectivity {
>
>   /**
>    * Get the network info
>    * @param context
>    * @return
>    */
>   public static NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo(Context context){
>       ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
>       return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
>   }
>
>   /**
>    * Check if there is any connectivity
>    * @param context
>    * @return
>    */
>   public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
>       NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
>       return (info != null && info.isConnected());
>   }
>
>   /**
>    * Check if there is any connectivity to a Wifi network
>    * @param context
>    * @param type
>    * @return
>    */
>   public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context){
>       NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
>       return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
>   }
>
>   /**
>    * Check if there is any connectivity to a mobile network
>    * @param context
>    * @param type
>    * @return
>    */
>   public static boolean isConnectedMobile(Context context){
>       NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
>       return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
>   }
>
>   /**
>    * Check if there is fast connectivity
>    * @param context
>    * @return
>    */
>   public static boolean isConnectedFast(Context context){
>       NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
>       return (info != null && info.isConnected() && Connectivity.isConnectionFast(info.getType(),info.getSubtype()));
>   }
>
>   /**
>    * Check if the connection is fast
>    * @param type
>    * @param subType
>    * @return
>    */
>   public static boolean isConnectionFast(int type, int subType){
>       if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
>           return true;
>       }else if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
>           switch(subType){
>           case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
>               return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
>           case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
>               return false; // ~ 14-64 kbps
>           case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
>               return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
>           case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
>               return true; // ~ 400-1000 kbps
>           case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
>               return true; // ~ 600-1400 kbps
>           case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
>               return false; // ~ 100 kbps
>           case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
>               return true; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
>           case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
>               return true; // ~ 700-1700 kbps
>           case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
>               return true; // ~ 1-23 Mbps
>           case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
>               return true; // ~ 400-7000 kbps
>           /*
>            * Above API level 7, make sure to set android:targetSdkVersion 
>            * to appropriate level to use these
>            */
>           case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD: // API level 11 
>               return true; // ~ 1-2 Mbps
>           case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B: // API level 9
>               return true; // ~ 5 Mbps
>           case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP: // API level 13
>               return true; // ~ 10-20 Mbps
>           case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN: // API level 8
>               return false; // ~25 kbps 
>           case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE: // API level 11
>               return true; // ~ 10+ Mbps
>           // Unknown
>           case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
>           default:
>               return false;
>           }
>       }else{
>           return false;
>       }
>   }
>
> }
> ```
>
> Also make sure to add this permission to you AndroidManifest.xml
>
> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
> ```
>
> Sources for network speeds include wikipedia &
>   http://3gstore.com/page/78_what_is_evdo_mobile_broadband.html

Comment: I tried with CONNECTIVITY_ACTION and other types of event without success. CONNECTIVITY_ACTION works only between wifi and mobile data.

Comment: It should work between different mobile connections too (in fact it does, tested). When you receive the action, call `ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()` and then `NetworkInfo.getSubtype()`. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8548926/2444099) should give you everything you need.

Comment: I'm using exactly this class for other purposes. But, my problem is the EVENT, not how call a method to get informations.